# Как поменять альфа канал у bitmap в рантайме?

Tags: android

Или придется фотошопить и 2е картинки использовать?

Я ошибся, мне нужен был bitmap.

Есть картинка, и нужно сделать чтобы она меняла интенсивность (всего 2 положения: нормальная и посветлее), так вот можно ли добиться этого альфа каналом, или целесообразнее поменять картинке параметры в ФШ и потом использовать 2е картинки (измененную и не изменённую)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
view.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Правда работает начиная с API lvl 11

Comment: Спасибо! Не успел ещё туда залезть.

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.getDrawable().setAlpha(100); // 0-255
imageView.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам искал ответ на поставленный вопрос. Данные тут ответы помогут сделать View прозрачным, но не сам bitmap. Вот так можно сделать bitmap прозрачным:

```
bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
```